# Is there any downside to using Windows offline update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, wsus

In the past I've had numerous problems with Windows Update. I started using [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) and found it worked extremely well. So well, in fact I don't see the point of using normal Windows Update (or whatever it's called) anymore. For example with WSUS Offline Update it automatically reboots the computer to complete installation.

My question is, is there any benefits to using Window's built in "check for updates" as opposed to the WSUS Offline Update? To be clear, the computer I'm thinking of using it on can connect to Windows Update normally.

I ask this question because I just installed Windows and find it awful suspicious that it has already finished installing updates after 30 minutes.

Comment: Besides it has bugs, and it doesn't support or find all updates as they are released and requires its own updates?

Comment: @Ramhound what makes you say it doesn't find all updates?

Comment: Besides the years of Administrator experience I have?  The simple fact the program receives updates in order to support released windows updates.

Comment: Would it be bad to run both to see if anything is missed?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

Is there any downside to using Windows offline update?

**Answer:**

Yes there are downsides:

> On both sides, i.e. for download and installation parts, WSUS Offline
>   Update uses Microsoft's update catalog file wsusscn2.cab to
>   dynamically determine the required patches. This catalog file contains
>   at least all the updates classified as "critical" and "security
>   relevant", but it does not necessarily contain all "important" and
>   "optional" ones.

I agree with @Ramhound from the comments, I do not recommend it.

[Source](http://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=172)